# Telegram bot editMessageCaption 429 request limit

Tags: bots, telegram, limit, rate-limiting

I have a channel with ~15 bots which post 3-7 photo with caption message per minute.
Later I want to edit caption of some of this message (editMessageCaption bot method) but unexpectedly get such error in some case:

> {"description":"Too Many Requests: retry after
> 6","error_code":429,"ok":false,"parameters":{"retry_after":6}}

Most editing requests are successful, but the error may appear even if I try to edit 3 minute old not edited message from 1.5 min IDLE bot (same bot that post message, of course). This is strange, because I don't know what the limits are related to in this case. I try to use different ip-address, but can't find any difference in successful/unsuccesful request ratio.

Probably this is global limit for channel or for bot owner account?
If you have encountered this situation, please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

That's Bot's limit. Since telegram have floodwaits use try and except and except and wait for the floodwait to cool and try again.

Comment: I don't think so. Please consider situation which described in original post. Edit request from bot that have been IDLE for 1.5 minutes (no send or edit message at this time) was unsuccessful.